# Render HTML with a reliant Script in react

Tags: html, reactjs, frontend

I have the below HTML i am trying to insert in to a react component:

```
<div id="wg-api-football-livescore"
     data-host="api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
     data-refresh="60"
     data-key="Your-Api-Key-Here"
     data-theme=""
     data-show-errors="false"
     class="api_football_loader">
</div>
<script
    type="module"
    src="https://widgets.api-sports.io/football/1.1.8/widget.js">
</script>
```

The html renders a widget that is called via the script tag at the bottom. I have tried a few work arounds like webpack which I am not too clear on to be honest.

A few things about it though. There are details contained within the div tag such as data-key which contains my api key among other details such as data-host etc. I'm not too sure if these are headers that should be sent as part of a GET request?

I have also tried the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "https://widgets.api-sports.io/football/1.1.8/widget.js";
        script.async = true;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
        return () => {
            document.body.removeChild(script); // This will remove the script on unmount
        };
    }, []);
```

But receive the error:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module**

Is there an easier quicker way to find a solution to this? or if anyone has experience any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a way through using iframe tags. This places a html document within the component i.e. the iframe serves as its own Html page essentially.

```
return (
        <div>
            <iframe
                scrolling='no'
                srcDoc={`
            <div
                id='wg-api-football-standings'
                data-host='v3.football.api-sports.io'
                data-key='insert-api-key'
                data-league={1}
                data-team=''
                data-season={2022}
                data-theme=''
                data-show-errors='false'
                data-show-logos='true'
                className='wg_loader'
            />
            <script
            type="module"
            src="https://widgets.api-sports.io/2.0.3/widgets.js"
        ></script>`}
            />
        </div>
    );
```